# Fantasy Gambling Rules

Tags: gambling

Why is something like ESPN's Streak for the Cash not considered gambling under law? streak.espn.go.com/en. It is clear this is a game of chance due to ESPN purposely picking games that statistically are 50 50

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to pay anything to participate.

The picks offered as part of Streak for the Cash are not statistically 50/50. There are often picks with vegas lines that correspond to 60-70% for one of the sides.

The test for whether something is a game of chance is not simply checking whether the options are 50/50.

Comment: so say you have a game where you get free coins everyday, but wager them with other people on either fantasy sports or just bets and if you get a certain number of coins you get a prize. Is this still considered gambling? You don't have to pay anything to participate @Dawn

Comment: See http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/7049/online-gambling-rules

Comment: Wait... but doesn't streak for cash offer a Cash reward for winning a certain amount of "games"? How is this not considered gambling? @Dawn

Comment: @dodgeroebuck You don't have to pay anything to participate.

Comment: but say you don't have to pay anything to participate in a game where you earn points but its for fantasy sports or some skill based game. Then you can spend those points on prizes like a Streak for Cash's Grand Prize thing. You technically aren't wagering anything of value. How is this considered gambling? Thanks for your help btw. I really appreciate it @Dawn